# Age-weighted democracy - is it possible?

Tags: democracy, voting, demographics, social-justice

A pure democracy gives equal voting rights for voters in the society regardless of their demographics (age, gender, or ethnicity).

However, in many referendums, younger voters have a different say from older people, and the there may be a true differential impact of the referendum result on people from different generations (e.g., Brexit).

For example, a result of 'Yes' in a referendum could be overall beneficial for older, more conservative people while being in the same time harmful for more ambitious younger generations who have longer life expectancy.

In a democratic political system, can votes be weighted by life expectancy based on voters' age? Or would this be considered age discrimination?

Comment: Voting to close for ageism, subjectivity,  and the dubious concept that the Brexit would hurt the young

Comment: This doesn't justify closing the question. You could rather put your argument in an answer.

Comment: @Orion The subjectivity part does. Asking whether this would be a good idea is a question about opinion, and is outside the scope of the SE.

Comment: The "(and should)" makes it opinion-based.

Comment: Juggling the election system for a different answer looks like gerrymandering and other deceptive practices. If you don't like the outcome of an election, you might start by examining the reasons the election went the way it did, and then adjusting your campaign for a broader appeal. It's called democracy, and it works... when people look for answers, not excuses.

Comment: @tj1000 You are right _only if_ we assume the current election system is perfect.

Comment: But wouldn't the young people be less world wise and less experienced / more idealistic and so their votes be worth less? Think of all those students who thought communism/socialism would be great but changed their tune as the got older and learned more about the real world...

Comment: @colmde Ok, then shouldn't older people's votes worth more?

Comment: "a result of 'Yes' in a referendum could be overall beneficial for the older [generation]". In the case of Brexit, I would question your assumption that people vote for their own financial interests. Stopping the flow of immigrant labor, falling real estate prices, and an increase in price of goods, on a fixed income, would affect the older the generation the most -- even if they did vote in favor of it.

Comment: This question might as well be asked in the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange. In the real world, no one trusts each other where it comes to redefining who has the right to vote. And usually, the older people are the ones that have accumulated the most power and the most wealth since they've been alive the longest. And I can tell you right now that they're not going to stand for such a selfless disenfranchisement. No one would.

Comment: @Orion - my point is there is a huge number of variables which could weight different people's weights in different ways, how much it affects them, their expertise in the subject matter, the emotion they feel about it, their worldly experience, how much tax they've paid, how much they've contributed to society, how much they could contribute to society if the referendum is passed or not, etc. etc. Each one is incredibly arguable - the only fair way of doing it is one-person one-vote.

Comment: @user9790: FYI, Brexit has already hurt not only the young but the country as a whole ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_effects_of_Brexit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_effects_of_Brexit)).

Answer (score 2):

This would definitely be considered age discrimination.  It shifts the balance of power towards the young.  And because the young vote less often, it would shift towards a smaller portion of the overall population.

You identify the one significant pro.  It would shift the power towards those who might be affected the longest time.

The accompanying con though is that there is already a way for the young to address that.  They will only be young and outvoted by the old for a limited time.  Eventually the old will die or at least become sick enough to no longer vote.  So the young can then win those votes and change the law.  Until they do so, then the young and old should share that responsibility.  The old have just as much right to control the next year of their life as the young do.  Once the old are no longer there, the now older but previously young can step forward and join with the even younger for a new result.

There is also the problem of the young having less life experience.  I.e. many people look back on decisions they made when young and think about how they wouldn't do that again.  This gives more power to the people with the least ability to aim it.

Under this logic, shouldn't the unborn get the greatest influence?  They will be impacted more than anyone living, as they have a longer life expectancy.  And there are so many of them.  You can go forward an arbitrary period of time so as to have more unborn people than living people.

Comment: Re *"the young vote less often"*: in the *current* system yes, but it might be that under a hypothetical life-expectancy weighted system the aged would vote less frequently *per capita* than the young.

Comment: Re *"less life experience"*: of course such added experience might be offset by fading mental powers and various corrupting obligations -- older voters might be more conservative not because they believe in conservatism, but because they can't adapt to change, (*e.g.* suppose an old voter with valuable tobacco stock votes for some tobacco-sponsored racist because he's afraid he can't pick a more lucrative investment, even thought that voter disapproves of cancer and racism).

Comment: Perhaps rather than weighting the votes, the system could be changed so that decisions are less permanent. Taking Brexit as an example, by the time it happens enough old people will have died to reverse the result, but actually re-joining the EU is then going to be extremely difficult even if it's what people want.

Comment: Not sure that old people have more life experience than young people. At least, societies evolve and part of that life experience is useless in the modern society. Many elders have difficulties with globalization and/or new technologies. Life experience or political wisdom is not an increasing function of age.

Comment: The last paragraph is pure slippery slope fallacy.

Answer (score 2):

Voting weighted by life expectancy is age-discrimination, but so is the current system of limiting voting to those *over* a certain age.  A reverse system could also be tried, where votes are weighted by total years lived, so that elders had more voting points.  It might also be argued, if we liken urbanization to youth, that the US apportionment of electoral votes by state, where [a Wyoming voter has three times the  voting power of a New York voter](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/map_of_the_week/2012/11/presidential_election_a_map_showing_the_vote_power_of_all_50_states.html?via=gdpr-consent), is a bit like the reverse system.

Life expectancy vote weighting effects might occur wherever the young disagree with the old:

- Unpopular wars with drafts.
- Student aid, loan, and grant policies.  Public schools.
- Taxation in general, property tax in particular.
- Contraband laws.
- Codification of topical social mores.
- Age of candidates.

It seems unprofitable to speculate as to which of those might be pros and cons.